# Move Directory on Save From Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm working on an Eclipse project, in which, a subfolder is a PHP project. I'd like to set up the eclipse project so that when I run a build, the PHP project subfolder is copied to an external folder on my filesystem (my web root).

I understand that there are probably several ways to do this, so I was hoping I could get some helpful feedback detailing a few of the best/easiest ways to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that the build process is meant for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to do this. What I did instead, since I'm working on a PHP project, is to work on the project directly from my webroot.

I use subclipse/subversion to update my working copy and my development cycle works fine like this. In my case, working on the project elsewhere on the filesystem and then having to move it after each change is pretty much just an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to hook up to the build process, you would use the org.eclipse.core.resources.builders extension point and define a custom builder class that extends from org.eclipse.core.resources.IncrementalProjectBuilder.